# How to escape forward slash in synonym mapping for elastic search?

Tags: elasticsearch, solr, synonym

I am using synonym analyzer for my elastic index and my synonym mapping is like this (Solr format):

```
Mechanic,Machinist,Welder,Bike Repairer,Car Repairer,Autoworks,Technician,Machine operator => Mechanic
Nurse,Nursing,Hospital Female assistant,Nursing Attendant,Female Caretaker,Male Caretaker,Ward Boy,Pharmacist,Pharmacy,Healthcare => Nurse
Office Assistant,Office Boy,Office Helper,Office Attendant,Helper => Office Assistant/Helper
Security,Guard,Gate man,Gateman,Gate Keeper,Gatekeeper,Watcher,Security Keeper,Watchman,Night Guard => Security/Guard
```

The synonym cases with forward slash are not working.
I have tried to escape the forward slashes '/' with back slashes '\' in the mapping file but that does not seem to work. The cases not involving forward slashes are working perfectly fine. Any suggestions?